# Como faço pra imprimir um hexa em c através do printf?

Tags: c, hexadecimal, printf

```
//exemplo  
mascara=0xFF;  
blue= COR1 & mascara; //cor um macro que eu usei  
printf("**%s**\n", blue); //duvida em negrito
```

Comment: Utilize o '{}' do editor para formatar seu código. Assim fica mais organizado.

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir um HEX em C temos as opções:

- `%i` Imprime o valor inteiro correspondente.
- `%x` Imprime o valor HEX normal

Você pode também especificar quantas casas quer na impressão usando %4x para 4 casas por exemplo ou %04x para completar os números à esquerda com zeros.

Veja no [ideone](https://ideone.com/hsog0K).